# Android - Do creating many small short lived objects affect performance?

Tags: java, android, performance, dalvik, strategy-pattern

I am creating a 2D game in Android. I am confused on how to efficiently write my code or it would pose performance issues in the long run.

Currently I am using strategy pattern. This is my code.

```
public void setCharAnimDirection(
        CharacterAnimationDirection charAnimDirection) {
    if(charAnimDirection == CharacterAnimationDirection.NorthEast ||
               charAnimDirection == CharacterAnimationDirection.NorthWest) {
        if (super.getCharAnimType() == CharacterAnimationType.Attack) {
            super.setCharAnim(new AttackBackAnim());
        } else if (super.getCharAnimType() == CharacterAnimationType.Battle) {
            super.setCharAnim(new BattleBackAnim());
        } else {
        }   
    } else {
        if (super.getCharAnimType() == CharacterAnimationType.Attack) {
            super.setCharAnim(new AttackFrontAnim());
        } else if (super.getCharAnimType() == CharacterAnimationType.Battle) {
            super.setCharAnim(new BattleFrontAnim());
        } else {
        }   
    }
```

The problem here is, A Character always changes its direction in my game, thus creating a small object everytime. 
I have read a old book(2009) about creating small short lived objects, that when they pile up, it forces the virtual machine(dalvik in my case) to do a garbage collection, thus pausing other processes and sometimes giving you lags. But I am not sure if it still currently applies to the latest virtual machines and garbage collections.

So,would placing their method in one class and doing an if-else would enhance performance or just giving me a messy code? 
For example this code.

```
        if (character.getCharAnimDirection() == CharacterAnimationDirection.NorthWest) {
            g.drawPixmap(AnimAssets.battleBackAnim, character.getX()
                    + BTL_XOFFSET, character.getY() + BTL_YOFFSET,
                    frameBlock, 0, BTL_FRAME_WIDTH, BTL_FRAME_HEIGHT);
        } else if (character.getCharAnimDirection() == CharacterAnimationDirection.SouthWest) {
            g.drawPixmap(AnimAssets.battleFrontAnim, character.getX()
                    + BTL_XOFFSET, character.getY() + BTL_YOFFSET,
                    frameBlock, 0, BTL_FRAME_WIDTH, BTL_FRAME_HEIGHT);
        } else if (character.getCharAnimDirection() == CharacterAnimationDirection.NorthEast) {
            g.drawMirroredPixmap(AnimAssets.battleBackAnim,
                    character.getX() - BTL_XOFFSET + 40, character.getY()
                            + BTL_YOFFSET, frameBlock, 0, BTL_FRAME_WIDTH,
                    BTL_FRAME_HEIGHT);
        } else {
            g.drawMirroredPixmap(AnimAssets.battleFrontAnim,
                    character.getX() - BTL_XOFFSET + 20, character.getY()
                            + BTL_YOFFSET, frameBlock, 0, BTL_FRAME_WIDTH,
                    BTL_FRAME_HEIGHT);
        }
```

Or is there a more efficient and cleaner way to implement this?

Your help would greatly be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell how bad the GC will be, but I can answer this part:

> So,would placing their method in one class and doing an if-else would enhance performance or just giving me a messy code?

No, messy code is what the programmer does. Not being able to use the strategy pattern may writing cleaner code harder, but it's no real excuse.

There are 4 cases and you can create 4 objects and reuse them. This even simpler than creating them on the fly.

You already have `CharacterAnimationDirection.NorthWest` etc. Let's hope it's an enum and add methods like `xOffset` and `yOffset` to it. Now you code can be something like

```
CharacterAnimationDirection direction = character.getCharAnimDirection();
g.drawMirroredPixmap(AnimAssets.battleFrontAnim,
    character.getX() + direction.xOffset(),
    character.getY() + direction.yOffset(),
    frameBlock, 0, BTL_FRAME_WIDTH, BTL_FRAME_HEIGHT);
```

This doesn't look messy, right?

Comment: it doesnt. but I need to use the g.drawPixmap method if its direction is NorthWest or SouthWest, otherwise the g.drawMirroredPixmap if its direction is NorthEast or SouthEast.

Comment: @steven0529: Then one `boolean`-returning method should do. Or something else... but it doesn't need to be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Using strategy pattern is already a good thing and you should use Switch Case statement instead.